# Key error in flask web app - (KeyError: <weakref at 0x0000023357A05F80; to 'Flask' at 0x00000233559F45E0>)

Tags: python, html, postgresql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I’m coding a web app using flask, I’ve connected to an external database service using the correct syntax (so the URI in the code is removed for obvious reasons additionally the secret key will not be "replace-later" in final product). I want to know if there is any way to  pinpoint what is causing the key error? The libraries I’m using for the web app are flask, flask-wtf, flask-sqlalchemy; additionally as I want to connect to a Postgres’s db I have downloaded Postgres utilities from the Postgres website and I have a DB host service available too . What could be the solution to this error?

Here is the main app code, this contains app logic and whatnot:

```
from models import *
 
app = Flask(__name__) 
app.secret_key = 'replace-later'
 
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']='**REMOVED**'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
 
@app.route("/", methods=['GET','POST']) 
def index(): 
 
    reg_form = RegistrationForm()
    if reg_form.validate_on_submit(): 
        username = reg_form.username.data
        password = reg_form.password.data
 
        user_object = User.query.filter_by(username=username).first()
        if user_object: 
            return "Username has been taken"
 
        user = User(username=username, password=password)
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
        return "Added to DB"
```

Here is the link to the the db model which interacts with the database I have set up as well as the main app file in order to add user's usernames and passwords:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
 
db = SQLAlchemy()
 
class User(db.Model):
    """ User model """
 
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(25), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=False)
```

here is an image of the traceback and the error: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJBxS.png)

I have resolved this issue by removing the duplicate "**db**" variable from both files and moving the database table model (class User) to the main python file (first one shown).

This however presents a new problem now I am trying to add a custom validator to another file I have for form logic this however with the previous changes gives me basically the same error. Here is the code I've ended up on.

There are 3 files:

This is the main web-app logic file containing routes and etc:

```
from wtform_fields import *
from libs import Flask, render_template


app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'replace-later'

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']='**REMOVED**'

# database model
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class User(db.Model):
    """ User model """

    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(25), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=False)


@app.route("/", methods=['GET','POST'])
def index():

    reg_form = RegistrationForm()

    if reg_form.validate_on_submit():
        username = reg_form.username.data
        password = reg_form.password.data


        user = User(username=username, password=password)
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
        return "Added to DB"

    return render_template("index.html", form=reg_form)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app.run(debug=True)
```

This is the libs file which holds all the imported libraries - **This was created as i thought this might be causing the error**

`from flask import Flask, render_template`

`from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy`

`from flask_wtf import FlaskForm`

`from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, SubmitField`

`from wtforms.validators import InputRequired, Length, EqualTo, ValidationError`

This is the form logic file:

```
from libs import SQLAlchemy, FlaskForm, StringField, PasswordField, SubmitField, InputRequired, Length, EqualTo, ValidationError
from application import User


class RegistrationForm(FlaskForm):
    '''Registration Form'''

    username = StringField('username_label',
                            validators=[InputRequired(message="Username Required"),
                            Length(min=4, max=25, message="Username must be between 4-20 charecters.")]
                            )
    password = PasswordField('password_label',
                            validators=[InputRequired(message="Password Required"),
                            Length(min=8, max=25, message="Password must be between 8-25 charecters.")]
                            )
    conf_pswd = PasswordField('conf_pswd_label',
                            validators=[InputRequired(message="Retype Password"),
                            EqualTo('password', message="Passwords must match")]
                            )

    submit_button = SubmitField('create')

    def validate_username(self, username):
        user_object = User.query.filter_by(username=username.data).first()
        if user_object:
            raise ValidationError("Username already exists")
```

This is the traceback for the error in the edited files: [Traceback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IlS5h.jpg)

My question is how can I firstly roll back the code back to the first instance (I'm using git so I am sure this is in some way possible) then resolve the key error in the first instance so that the DB model is in a separate file also that there is no libs file; Additionally if how would I be able to adapt the code in the second instance to match the first (*This is optional as I have a general idea on how to do it but help would be appreciated*).  Also are there any suggestions as to how I could tidy up my code so it's more understandable and formatted.

The main question is **how do I fix the KeyError** (In the first instance)?

I've tried just about everything - checking for memory leaks checking for duplicate keys and variables and stuff like that. When the issue is resolved I want the program to be able to add users and their passwords to the Database as well as allowing the fields to be checked using a custom validator - and other validators I may add.

Comment: You should only be declaring `db = SQLAlchemy` _once_. Then import it whereever it's needed.

Comment: @snakecharmerb so if I declared `db=SQLAlchemy(app)` like this in the db model file and removed it from the main file and imported it, it would work?

Comment: Yes.  But be careful to avoid circular imports (for example model imports app from main, main imports db from models). It may be easiest to have a third module that defines app and db.  A note that the code in models must be executed before db.create_all is called.

Comment: @snakecharmerb I've already created created a table through the terminal so the table exists - would this still work in this instance?

Comment: Yes, `create_all` will skip existing tables.

Comment: allright i think ive solved it, at least in the first instance - i just moved all the stuff for configuring the app and db to models from main as well as                                         `if __name__ == "__main__":`
                                             `app.run(debug=True)` - this shouldn't cause any issues down the line, right?

Comment: @snakecharmerb additionally this occurs twice in my code as per changes `if __name__ == "__main__":` `app.run(debug=True)` once in the models file and once in the main file, it doesn't start the website if both are not present - would this be an issue in the future or is it okay to leave as is?